# C# XML multiple subchild

Tags: c#, xml

Good day! Im trying to parse XML subchild using dataset. The thing is its not reading the "SiteCode" when it has multiple value.

for example:

[image]

```
string filePath = @"" + _clsPathIntervalSttngs.localPath + "/" + "hehe.xml";
               
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet()
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
// Then display informations to test
foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
     Console.WriteLine(table);
     for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; ++i)
     {
         Console.Write("\t" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName.Substring(0, Math.Min(6, table.Columns[i].ColumnName.Length)));
         Console.WriteLine();
     }
     foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; ++i)
         {
              Console.Write("\t" + row[i]);
         }
              Console.WriteLine();
     }
}
```

this is what it is returning.

[image]

Its returning a 0 value and selecting the Product instead of sitecode.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Try to post the xml as text (and format it. You can remove the xml namespaces if seeing as you have redacted them here) because it will be easy to copy and paste that to check. As it is, someone will have to type out that xml and it will take more time to get a solution and most will not make the effort.

Comment: "using dataset" - why, is that a hard requirement? Because that is old and will not accept all xml forms.

Comment: If using dataset is an old. What do you suggest that is better than the said function?

Comment: The method is reading creating two tables.  The SiteCode results is in Table[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to check the code because I just took something similar I had lying around and changed it to look at your document hierarchy. I also didn't use a `DataSet`. Consider the following code:

```
var filePath = "<path to your file.xml>";
var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var items = from item in xml.Descendants("Product").Elements()
            select item.Value;
Array.ForEach(items.ToArray(), Console.WriteLine);
```

That should show you the values of each element under product. If you want the whole element, remove the `.Value` in the select clause of the LINQ query.

**Update**

I'm now projecting to an anonymous type. You'll get one of these for each Product element in the file.

```
var items = from item in dataset.Descendants("Product")
            select new
            {
                RefCode = item.Element("RefCode").Value,
                Codes = string.Join(", ", item.Elements("SiteCode").Select(x => x.Value)),
                Status = item.Element("Status").Value
            };
Array.ForEach(items.ToArray(), Console.WriteLine);
```

I have flattened the codes to a comma separated string but you can keep the `IEnumerable` or `ToList` it as you wish.

Comment: Hi! How can i get the value in the element Refcode? 
String a = items.ToArray()....;

Comment: Do you want just the refcode? or all of them? The first value that appears should be the refcode. Let me make a few changes and get back to you.

Comment: @AngeloSanchez I've updated the code based on what you have specified.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using xml Linq :

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {

```
    const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Load(FILENAME);

        List<Product> products = doc.Descendants("Product").Select(x => new Product()
        {
            refCode = (string)x.Element("RefCode"),
            siteCode = x.Elements("SiteCode").Select(y => (int)y).ToArray(),
            status = (string)x.Element("Status")
        }).ToList();



    }

}
public class Product
{
    public string refCode { get; set; }
    public int[] siteCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi! this is working fine for me but how do i loop inside of it so i could get all the data i need in the xml?

Comment: I updated code to give a List<Product>.  Without seeing the full xml I can't give a single answer since I do not know what you mean by "All The Data".  There are many ways of parsing an xml and depending on the size of the xml file, the structure of the xml, and the amount of data you need to extract will depend on which method is the best to use.